# Cannot perform a non-multi update on a time-series collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series

Hi I am using newly Timeseries mongodb collection. My mongodb version is 5.0.6. I am following [this](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/time-series-candlestick/) tutorial. I create a collection like this.

```
   db.createCollection("ticker", {
     timeseries: {
        timeField: "time",
        metaField: "metadata",
    },
});
```

I inserted the sample document like this.

```
db.ticker.insertOne({
 time: ISODate("20210101T01:00:00"),
 symbol: "BTC-USD",
 price: 34114.1145,
 metadata: { a: ""}
});
```

When I am trying to update metadata field it gives above error. As mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/) is limitation you can only update metaField but still it is giving above error. Here is the update code

```
db.ticker.update({ "metadata.a": "a" }, { $set: { "metadata.d": "a" } })

write failed with error: {
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 72,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot perform a non-multi update on a time-series collection"
    }
}
```

Need help what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding **`{ multi: true }`** config.

If you check [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/), there are still some limitations for updating time-series collections.

> Update commands must meet the following requirements:
>
> - The query may only match on metaField field values.
> - The update command may only modify the metaField field value.
> - The update must be performed with an update document that contains only update operator expressions.
> - The update command may not limit the number of documents to be updated. You must use an update command with multi: true or the
>   updateMany() method.
> - The update command may not set upsert: true.

Comment: Yes it worked now using update many or multi true.

Comment: How does the final command look like? @GhazanfarKhan

Comment: db.ticker.updateMany({ "metadata.a": "a" },{$set: { "metadata.a": "b"}}) or db.ticker.update({ "metadata.a": "a" },{$set: { "metadata.a": "b"}}, { multi: true })